# Проблема с компиляцией в pymorphy2 актуальных словарей из XML в DAWG

Tags: python, pymorphy2

Как откомпилировать актуальные версии словарей?
Делаю так:
1 компилирую питон 3.5.1 (требование совместимости) в домашний каталог
2 через его pip3 ставлю pymorhy2
3 Скачиваю исходный словарь в виде xml
4 Компилирую командой
pymorphy dict compile
5 получаю словари в каталоге dict
6 подсовываю их в /site-packages//pymorphy2_dicts
7 ругается на meta.json
8 все ломается на этапе ввода

```
>>> morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer(path="/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2_dicts/data.compiled")
```

с выводом

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2/analyzer.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.dictionary = opencorpora_dict.Dictionary(path)
  File "/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2/opencorpora_dict/wrapper.py", line 18, in __init__
    self._data = load_dict(path)
  File "/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2/opencorpora_dict/storage.py", line 45, in load_dict
    meta = _load_meta(_f('meta.json'))
  File "/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2/opencorpora_dict/storage.py", line 148, in _load_meta
    meta = json_read(filename, parse_float=str)
  File "/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2/utils.py", line 96, in json_read
    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf8') as f:
  File "/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 895, in open
    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2_dicts/data.compiled/meta.json'
```

9 Понятно что проблема с meta.json сравнивая его с тем что скачан по зависимостям , я вношу в него нужные коррективы и на него ругани больше нет, но оно все равно все падает с таким выводом. Тут, я так понял, что-то не пошло с двоичными словарями.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2/analyzer.py", line 177, in __init__
    self.prob_estimator = probability_estimator_cls(path)
  File "/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2/analyzer.py", line 65, in __init__
    self.p_t_given_w = ConditionalProbDistDAWG().load(cpd_path)
  File "dawg.pyx", line 394, in dawg.CompletionDAWG.load (src/dawg.cpp:8095)
OSError: It's not possible to read file stream
```

При работе со словарем скаченным по зависимостям все хорошо.
Запускаю в jmorphy - та же история (библиотека dawg общая?).

Может кто-то сказать в чем дело?

UPD: тут пока писал пришел совет что pymorphy2 надо ставить так (уже на питоне 3.6.3)

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2
```

Но тогда он не содержит CLI для компиляции. Для этого отдельный скрипт https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2-dicts .
Однако с их помощью так же не удается откомпилировать:

```
PC:~/Developing/pymorphy2-dicts$ python3 build-dict.py dict.opcorpora.xml data
DEBUG  2018-03-29 01:11:42  Creating output folder data
INFO   2018-03-29 01:11:42  dictionary v0.92, rev405410
INFO   2018-03-29 01:11:42  parsing XML dictionary
Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
```

Comment: Вопрос скорее на багтрекер Pymorphy2, чем сюда. Правильно что туда написали)

Answer (score 1):

Да, мне там ответили https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2/issues/108 .
Не все решается кодом из пакетов, что-то из реп, но решается. Проблему можно считать закрытой.
UPD:
Само решение

1. Создаем окружение (python3, pip3, jdk etc)
2. ставим не из питоновских реп, а из гита командой pip3 install
   git+https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2
3. ставим актуальную библиотеку lxml командой pip3 install --user
   'lxml<4.2.0'
4. качаем скрипт компиляции git clone
   https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2-dicts
5. качаем актуальный словарь wget
   http://opencorpora.org/files/export/dict/dict.opcorpora.xml.bz2
6. распаковываем его bzip2 -dk dict.opcorpora.xml.bz2
7. запускаем компиляцию python3 build-dict.py dict.opcorpora.xml data
8. имеем откомпилированный словарь в каталоге data, который можно
   подсунуть pymorphy2 двумя способами

а)подменить каталог вида `python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2_dicts_ru`
б)указать путь до словаря при создании экземпляра анализатора

```
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer(path="/home/victor/DevelopTools/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymorphy2_dicts_ru/data")
```

для jmorphy можно подменить в виде каталога `/company/evo/jmorphy2/%s/pymorphy2_dicts` , где %s язык (ru|uk)